# CSS, HTML layout: relative div inside absolute div flows outside its container

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

(Apologies in advance if this is answered elsewhere. I looked around and couldn't find anything that seemed to apply.)

I have a layout with absolute and relative positioning for divs to sit in their appropriate positions, which almost works.

http://jsfiddle.net/dex3703/TZzKN/

The #centercontainer (red) is intended to let #mainsection (orange) sit inside all the other content. I have absolute and relative positioning that I thought should work, but I have these problems:

- #mainsection's bottom extends beyond #centercontainer by about 20px.
- bottom, left, right, top don't have an effect. Using bottom: 20px to lift the bottom up doesn't work.
- If I don't have height: 100% on #mainsection--which I sense is wrong--it and the divs inside have no height! Only a little sliver of #contentsection is visible at the top of #mainsection.

I'm only interested in this working in Chrome and IE9 as well. Hope that makes things easier.

I'm sure this is some noob problem so am grateful in advance. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you're understanding the roles of `relative` and `absolute` in reverse. You give the container relative positioning so that children can be absolutely positioned within (otherwise absolute positioning 'bubbles' up until it finds a valid container, usually the page itself).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that simply flipping the two positioning types won't fix the problem; it will change the layout model enough that you basically need to rewrite. ;-) I'm not actually convinced you need absolute positioning at all.

Comment: @GregPettit - Thanks for the explanation. HTML/CSS layout is baffling to me and I'm still making these kinds of mistakes. The flexbox is far easier but I wanted something that would work on older IE browsers. Are you saying I don't need absolute positioning for this entire layout?

Comment: Pretty much. With layout there are always dozens of ways to skin the cat. There are certainly ways to do what you want to do without using absolute positioning. I think there's a time and place for absolute positioning, but often you'll have a more flexible layout without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set width and height for #mainsection to be 100%, you are telling it to be the same width and height as #centercontainer, excluding padding. There are 60px on each side because the padding of #centercontainer is 60px left and right.

The reason #mainsection extends below #centercontainer is that #breadcrumbcontainer is pushing it down by 40px (the height of #breadcrumbcontainer). It only extends down 20px because there is also 20px bottom padding for #mainsection.

If you set the bottom padding of #centercontainer to the height of #breadcrumbcontainer (INCLUDING #breadcrumbcontainer's top and bottom margins), that should fix the problem. It's probably not the most elegant way to fix it. but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I marked this as the answer though I think the others also work, and agree my layout isn't ideal. This is for a prototype that will likely change a great deal, so was adapting another layout I had. Thanks for the help and explanation. I tried margin which didn't help and didn't think to try padding.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your CSS. It's still no nice stylesheet, but the design is not broken anymore.

```
@charset "utf-8";

/*
HTML4 layout
using absolute positioning to get layout to work without HTML5/CSS flexbox

colors:
#1E242D - html frame bg
#F3F3F3 - left nav
#FFFFFF - main content, inner menu
#267EB9 - drawer bg

#DBDBDB - nav and left nav border
#4F9DD7 - selected item blue

#FFFFFF - white text
#4A4A4A - darkest text, dividers
#767676 - middle dark text
#C1C1C1 - light text

*/

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100%;
    background: White;
    margin: 0;
}

body
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

p
{
    margin: 0;

}

/* from html5boilerplate */
nav ul, nav ol  
{
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#layoutdiv
{
    z-index: 100;    
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

}

#maindiv
{
    margin: 10px 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
}

header
{
    position: absolute; /* change to absolute positioning */
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;

    height: 60px;

}

header p
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

header span
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#logodiv
{
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#notifypanel
{
    width: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 110px;
    bottom: 70px;
    background-color: LemonChiffon;
}

#notifypanel img
{
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

.left
{
    float: left;

}

.right
{
    float: right;

}

ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;    
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;

}

li
{
    display: inline-block; /*need inline-block or height==0! */    
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;

}

#topnav
{

    /* position: absolute;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /* top: 55px; with absolute positioning, move its top to the header's bottom */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#topnav ul
{

    /*margin-left: 15px;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

#topnav li
{
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #767676;
    height: 100%;
    /*line-height: 5em;  for vertical alignment */

}

#topnav li:hover
{
    color: #1E242D;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

#topnav .selected
{
    background-color: #4F9DD7;
    color: White;
}

#centercontainer
{
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 60px;
    padding: 0 60px 20px 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    border: 1px solid red;

}

#breadcrumbcontainer
{

    top: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-family: Segoe UI Light;
    font-size: 3.6em;
    line-height: 0.8em;

}

#breadcrumb
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#viewcontrols
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 320px;
    text-align: right;
}

#mainsection
{

    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* mainseciton won't display unless 100%, but height is off, doesn't quite sit in containing div */
    position: relative;
    top:30px;
    background-color: Aqua;

    border: 2px solid orange;

}

#contentsection
{

    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* makes padding, margins behave like XAML */
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;

    background-color: AliceBlue; /* remove later */
    display: inline-block;

}

#leftnav
{
    width: 200px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

#leftnav li
{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 7px 0 7px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB;


}

#leftnav img
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 24px;
    height: 22px;
}

#leftnav p
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#leftnav .selected
{
    background-color: #4F9DD7;
}

#leftnav .selected:hover
{
    background-color: #4387B7;
}

#leftnav li:hover
{
    background-color: #FdFdFd;
}


footer
{
    background: #267EB9;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1em;  /* vertically centers header content .. see http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html */
    text-align: center; /* centers the center button div */
}

footer img
{
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}

footer p
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: super;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.footerleft
{
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 17px;
}

.footerright
{
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 17px;
}

.footercenter
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
}

.footercenter div
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.footercenter p
{
    display: block;
}

.footercenter img
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Greg: Thanks for the fiddle I have had no time to make one.

Comment: I don't think this quite works. When you shrink the browser window vertically, #mainsection doesn't stay centered and show scrollbars for the content. It scrolls down behind the footer.

Comment: I have only fixed it for the fiddle view. The whole CSS needs to be cleaned up. I don't think that the whole approach of the design is very senseful.